# Simulate Kafka broker behaviour for testing resiliency

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

[AWS MSK](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/): During one of the security patch updates, we saw that our producer, which was using an *acks=all* configuration, faced latency for writes since it was blocking on send.

We decided to change this configuration and now want to test this with the behavior of Kafka producer full, etc.

Is there something that can be used to simulate this?

Answer (score 0):

MSK does not expose an API to allow you stop a broker. They only expose a reboot API. Therefore there isn't any way to currently test patching impact.

However, please note that the behaviour of `acks=all` during a broker unavailable is not to block. As long as *min.isr* is met the produce will still succeed. See *[Kafka Acks Explained](https://betterprogramming.pub/kafka-acks-explained-c0515b3b707e)*.

Kafka is designed to be resilient to broker unavailability as best practise configurations are followed which I believe MSK documents here: *[Best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/bestpractices.html)* (MSK)

If you experienced a producer blocking with `acks=all` then either *min.isr* was breached causing offline partitions or a broker was believed by Kafka to be in isr and leader, but not reachable. I would recommend you check the isr and offline partition metrics to verify which was the case here. Assuming a three-broker cluster with rf=3 and min.isr=2, one broker offline should != offline partition.

If the broker was alive, but not reachable, I would verify the network health on both sides. You can check broker alive times with Kafka logs and [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) metrics.